# putting a .java file into .war

Tags: java, netbeans, war

My professor asks us to submit out projects in WAR files, and he says my project will get a 0 if the WAR doesn't include my .JAVA file.

I see it includes the .CLASS file but he said thats not enough, how can i get the .WAR file to pack with the .JAVA inside of it?

EDIT:
To compress the file i'm using the clean and build option in Netbeans.  the WAR file appears in the build folder

Comment: how are you generating the war now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is in Eclipse, you will include source under the export WAR option.

**Update**

In the war export panel, there should be an "Excluded file types"  make sure to remove `*.java`

Comment: NetBeans also should have an option. It's general.

Comment: Found it, thanks!
had to right click on the project and go through the properties menu

Answer (score 0):

WAR file is just an archive, understandable with any ZIP archiver, like 7-zip. You can put anything you want into WAR.

Answer (score 0):

Look for section "Including Source Files in the WAR File"

http://users.cis.fiu.edu/~downeyt/webdev/netbeans.html

quoted from the link:

> From the properties screen, select Build -> Packaging. Edit the Exclude From WAR File box and remove **/*.java,.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to create the WAR file? If you use [apache ant](http://ant.apache.org) then add a `copy` task to your `build.xml` and then reference it in the default target e.g. with `<target name="dist" depends="copy-source"/>`

The task might look something like:

```
<target name="copy-source">
  <echo>Copying source files...</echo>
  <copy todir="${app.dir}/src">
    <fileset dir="${javasrc.dir}">
      <include name="**/*.java"/>
    </fileset>
  </copy>
</target>
```

ps. It is best to define the variables in an external `build.properties` file and never use hard-coded values in `build.xml`.
Also, have a look at http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/war.html and http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html

Answer (score 0):

In Netbeans.Right click your project. Select Project Properties.It will open a Project properties window. Select Build->Packaging from the Categories Tab. In the window that appears on right hand side, there is a text field: Exclude from WAR file. In that text field default value is: **/*.java,***/.form. In that text field remove the **/*.java value and click Ok.
 Now clean and build project. Now you will find the war file exported with .java sources under dist directory of your project.